# Get Drop down event inside a for each loop using knock out

Tags: knockout.js

Here is the sample Code
  I need to show the customer details in the Pages. I am showing Customer Details not as a single Record in the UI. For each Customer I am trying to Show details in the table. In the Each Customer table i need to display the Pagination. Below is the Sample Code used for displaying the Each Customer. For Pagination I  have previous Button a drop Down and a Next Button. Since when the drop down value is changed i need to show the next set for that particular Customer. Problem is i am not able to get the Dropdown event in knock out in the for each loop.

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li><span>
      <input type="button" class="btn dsg-back-btn" value="" title="Previous Page">
    </span></li>
    <li><span>
      <select class="queueQuery" data-bind="options: TablePageSize, optionsText: 'PageId', optionsValue: 'QueueId', optionsCaption: 'Select'">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="b66bc105-337c-4e5c-aead-6493a3ace358">1</option>
        <option value="b66bc105-337c-4e5c-aead-6493a3ace358">2</option>
        <option value="b66bc105-337c-4e5c-aead-6493a3ace358">3</option>
      </select></span></li>
    <li><span>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm dsg-next-btn" value="" title="Next Page"></span></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to update your customer details list when the select list value changes. Using the [value](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) binding on the select list with an observable property and subscribing to that observable should give you a way to capture the dropdown change and load new data in your view model.

JS:

```
var val = ko.observable();
val.subscribe(function (newVal) {
  // load new data into observable array bound to your list view
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="queueQuery" data-bind="options: TablePageSize, optionsText: 'PageId', optionsValue: 'QueueId', optionsCaption: 'Select', value: val">
```